# obtaining MOUSE_DX MOUSE_DY in winapi

Tags: windows, winapi, input, mouse

I need obtain a MOUSE_DX and MOUSE_DY values where
MOUSE_DX is a difference between MOUSE_X and MOUSE_PREV_X

someone give stupid answer to my that i can hide cursor substract
succesive  MOUSE_X between mouse move events, and when cursor
goes away from the centre of the sceen call ShowCursorPost to the
cantre of the screen - but this is a real hell : it is stupid perself also
calling ShowCursorPost generate fake mouse move events so 
then I would need to filter out this fake movements then (It is hell)

Is there some more reasonable way of obtaining the MOUSE_DX
MOUSE_DY I need?

//EDIT (more explaining for questions )

I want to use mouse as a steering device - something like mowing yaw/pitch/roll of the camera

For this purpose I need to gest something like MOUSE_DELTA_X MOUSE_DELTA_Y
where such numbers are indeed the MOUSE_X-MOUSE_PREV_X where MOUSE_X/Y are
coordinates of the mouse cursor given to me by WM_MOUSEMOVE

allright - this works to some extent but not much:
I need the DX DY walues related to mouse movements but do not need
a mouse cursor at all, when mouse cursor hits the screen edge i will
not gest full DX but some cutted and then all zeros

To prevent this i call (as somebody advice me) SetCursorPos when 
the cursor nears to the edge of the desktop (the window really becouse
I do not want him to exit my window) then I call SetCursorPos
to the centre of the client area (I also make cursor invisible, and
also clip it to the window size but it also brings a lot of
trouble, need to unclip the areo on alt+tab etc it is all tiresome
and it is all a complex workaround for such simple thing like obtaining 
DX DY)  I just do not need this f*cking invisible cursor moving on screen 
at all here - but I need mouse DX DY only

but let assume that this machinery with invisible cursor is tiresomely 
coded and debugged

the other trouble is that when I call SetCursorPos It also generates 
fake mouse movement backward and it generates fake DX and DY then 
(it is hard to filter - at least i do not know how to do it all
in a robust way)

(can this fake mouse move been easily filtered out?)

I did it all this invisible cursor clipping SetCursorPos and filtering
out the false DX DY but it is very ugly thing very error prone and
confusing - all this for simple obtaining (cursor independant/mouse 
related)DX DY for every move - this is hell It made me a long hours to
debug this stuff so I am angry - this is coding hell - this is terribly 
wrong so I am angry and need a good way of doing it

Comment: If you define DX as PREV_X - X, then you have to define what is PREV_X and X. If you define PREV_X and X as successive values of xPos in the WM_MOUSEMOVE message, then the answer is pretty straightforward, and given by David. If you are not happy with it, explain why (that is: really explain what you are trying to do)

Comment: Would you please explain what is the intended behavior of your program if the user move the mouse outside your window? Do you want to "block" the mouse inside your window? If yes, how do you intend to provide the user with a way to opt-out and get back his mouse?. I may propose an answer to your question, but I need clarifications.

Comment: Purpose is a camera in 3d application (or other things like zooming by moving mouse) I toggle between normal 'desktop cursor' and no cursor: inner steering by mouse - by pressing mouse wheel (toggle cursor on /off)

Comment: Would you mind telling why you don't try my answser (clip cursor, use timer on borders, no SetCursorPos)?

Comment: timer? i do not understand what are you talking about

Comment: I am talking about my answer.

Comment: You should read that answer! http://stackoverflow.com/a/20810292/1374704

Answer (score 2):

The `WM_MOUSEMOVE` event tells you the current position of the cursor. Well, it's actually the position of the cursor when the event was placed in the message queue, not quite the same thing. But the system does not keep track of the position of the cursor associated with the previous `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message. From this you can conclude that you will need to keep track of that.

So, do the following:

1. Declare variables to hold the previous cursor position.
2. Initialize those variables to the current cursor position.
3. Whenever you process `WM_MOUSEMOVE` you can compare the current position with the previous.
4. Once you have done that, update the previous cursor position to be equal to the current position, ready for the next `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message.

Comment: this work terribly bad and it brings HELL - I need MOUSE DELTAX DELTAY values but i do not want real physical cursor movement - especialt when it stops on the edge of the screen - so as i said I can make it invisible and when it is close to the edge of the screen SetCursorPos to the centre of the screen - BUT IT ALSO GENERATES fake mousemove event - that spoils result - also other troubles

Comment: I don't understand why you are SHOUTING. I also don't understand what you mean by wanting delta values, but not real physical cursor movement. I don't understand the relevance of `SetCursorPos`. I don't understand your comment about edge of the screen.

Comment: check out my EDiT i will do explaining

Comment: sorry it takes 20 minutes to write down

Comment: Nope, I don't really understand what your problem is and what your program is doing. Your anger seems to be stopping you explaining it clearly. Perhaps all you need to do is update prev_x and prev_y just before you call `SetCursorPos`?

Comment: this is like game when you control a camera by mouse - you use mouse DX dY but do not need the mouse cursor.. I do not update pREV_MOUSE_X - do not understand - the walues of X Y come from WM_MOUSEMOVE

Comment: If you want to know where the mouse was the last time `WM_MOUSEMOVE` was delivered, you have to remember it.

Comment: sure - seems that you do not understand what i described, I didi it like describet but it is wrong way, need a better way

Comment: I think I understand the basics. You are hoping that the system will have the values that you are looking for. But it doesn't you have to remember them. If you just update `prev_x` and `prev_y` before you call `SetCursorPos` then you'll handle the next `WM_MOUSEMOVE` as being a delta of zero.

Comment: well this is some idea for filteruing - but i am not sure if thiswillwork.. (now I am using other approach becouse I setCursorPos to same point say 320,200 In mousemove i just skip all the moves that ends in thispoint - It works but all the code is a mess - your idea will not improve it to much - this is all wrong)

Comment: It's not difficult to wrap this up. You do realise that if the system doesn't give you deltas, you'll need to synthesise them. What other option is there?

Comment: The trouble is not in counting deltas - but in "cheating" cursor - It would be easier if there is maybe some way to SetCursorPos without firing a fake mouse move... I am searching for such thing, is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Perhaps your proposed solution is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try:

Use the [ClipCursor function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383.aspx) to confine the cursor inside your window, or a sub-rect.

When the mouse hit your "border", start a timer. Stop the timer when the mouse leaves the border.
On each timer tick, you could generate a fake DX or DY.

The idea is to have the behavior of many games: you move the mouse, hitting a border, and then all behave as if you were still moving the mouse.