# How to track mouse movements without limiting it to screen size?

Tags: winapi, mousemove

I'm using WM_MOUSEMOVE to get changes in mouse position. When simulating "knobs" for example it's desired to let the user go up/down with mouse without any limits. In this cases I hide cursor and use SetCursorPos to change its position every time user moves with it and detect just the difference from the original position.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work - if I set the mouse position, it sometimes works, but sometimes is one or more pixels away, which is just wrong. And even bigger trouble is that after the call another WM_MOUSEMOVE seems to be delivered, which unfortunately does the same thing as it wants to move the cursor back to the original position again. So it ends up in an infinite cycle or settings mouse position and receiving messages until the user releases the mouse button.

What's the correct approach or what's the problem?

Comment: Could you use the scroll wheel on the mouse instead of x/y?

Comment: I think you can use DirectX to get the raw mouse-input messages, which are just "the mouse moved this far" rather than being translated to (and restricted to) screen coordinates. Try looking for DirectInput sample code.

Comment: I'm afraid mouse-wheel is too clumsy, it is used as well. DirectInput may work, but really I don't want to go into these deep waters, the software must work on very old machines, where DirectInput may not even be. Not to mention all the hard work just to get DX working for such trivial (but evidently not) thing.

Comment: Also, consider that if the user is moving your "knob" a long distance, they'll have to pick up the mouse and set it down again, potentially several times. You might consider letting them move the mouse around in circles (turning the knob) rather than moving straight up or down; it might be easier for the user, and could avoid your problem with screen boundaries.

Comment: I know, but I don't think it will be that bad. Personally I consider using "rotating by angle" extremely confusing and hard to use.

Comment: This is just self-inflicted misery from designing very inappropriate UI.  Knobs are only good for fingers.  Trackbars and spinners are good for mice.

Comment: Well, believe it or not, sometimes the situation is more complicated ;). And generalizing as "inappropriate UI" is inappropriate, since you don't know the subject, and doesn't help at all ;)

Answer (score 2):

The raw input system can do this - it lets you register for raw mouse input that isn't clipped or confined to the screen boundaries.

Broadly speaking, you register for raw input using [`RegisterRawInputDevices()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your window will then receive [`WM_INPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages, which you process using the [`GetRawInputData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

See [**Using Raw Input**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Raw input is overkill for this. Capture is sufficient and consistent with standard UI.

Comment: @RaymondChen Even when the mouse is captured it's still clipped to the screen boundaries isn't it?

Comment: True. I missed that detail.

Comment: Exactly! Screen is the problem. I'll chect the raw input.

Answer (score 0):

> I hide cursor and use SetCursorPos to change its position every time user moves with it and detect just the difference from the original position.

This is just plain wrong.  Instead, use [`SetCapture()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to capture the mouse.  All movements will be reported as `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages with coordinates that are relative to the specified window, even if the mouse is outside of that window, until you release the capture.

Comment: This is not the problem. In fact i use mouse capture. The problem is not the limit of the window, but limit of the screen! Imagine your knob is at about (50,50) in screen coordinates. Then you have only 50 vertical pixels up! Then the mouse messages stop coming, because the coordinates would be negative.

Comment: If you save the starting screen coordinates at the time of the capture, you can use the message coordinates, even if they are negative, to easily calculate the distance the mouse has moved from the starting coordinates. But if you are saying that the messages stop coming altogether when you reach the top of the screen, then so be it. As Jonathan suggested, you may need Raw Input to get past that.

Answer (score 0):

Asking the user to move the mouse continuously, even after the cursor hit the screen limit is a very bad idea in terms of User Interface, IMHO.

Some games have another approach: when the mouse hit the "limit", the game enter a special mode: things appears to function exactly *as if the mouse was moving*, even if the user don't move it. When the user wants to exit that mode, he just has to move the mouse *of the limit*.

Doing so requires a timer, armed when the mouse hit some limit, executing code periodically as if the mouse was moving. The timer is stopped when a real mouse movement makes it leaves the limit.

Comment: Well, in the field I'm working in it is a pretty common practice. I guess in games it would make sense though.

Comment: @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín And when the mouse is 50cm away, the user make it fly back to its original position?

Comment: Well, that's rather exagerated don't you think? ;) Besides the fact that you may simply be unlucky and the "knob" will be 10 pixels below the top of the screen making it virtually unusable, many people in my field are using other devices, such as tablets etc...

Answer (score 0):

Ok folks, so I found a solution simple enough:

The main problem is that SetCursorPos may not set the coordinates accurately, I guess it's because of some high resolution processing, nevertheless it's probably a bug. Anyway if SetCursorPos doesn't set the coordinates correctly (but +-1 in x and/or y) it also sends WM_MOUSEMOVE to the target window. As a result the window performs the exact same operation as before and this goes on and on.

So the solution is to remove all WM_MOUSEMOVE messages right after SetCursorPos:

```
MSG msg;
while (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_MOUSEMOVE, PM_REMOVE)) { };
```

Then retrieving the current mouse cursor pos using ::GetCursorPos .
It's ugly but seems to fix the problem. It basically seems that in some position of the mouse, the system always adds or subtracts 1 in either coordinate, so this way you let system do the weird stuff and use the new coordinates without trying to persuade system that your coordinates are the correct ones :).